# hide link page login gitlab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

Gitlab has several links on the login page, I want to hide these links, and I have found a file that contains these links, as I modify this file so that these links do not appear anymore. Thank you

[image]

> **FILE: devise.html.haml contains**

```
%hr
    .container
      .footer-links
        = link_to "Explore", explore_root_path
        = link_to "Help", help_path
        = link_to "About GitLab", "https://about.gitlab.com/"
```

Comment: what question ask do? :D Sorry - what you have asked is unclear. Can you please elaborate? What do you want it to do? What is it doing instead? what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: If you install GitLab via the Omnibus package then those changes will be overwritten the next time you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by commenting on the lines of code I wanted in the file **devise.html.haml contiene**, through `-#`